# How can I build a regular expression that matches any string containing all characters in a substring?

Tags: java, regex

I create a regular expression using StringBuilder that matches any string containing all characters in the string (or so I think).

```
StringBuilder myRegex = new StringBuilder("");
for (char c: myCharArray) {
  myRegex.append(String.format("?=.*%c", c));
}
```

I believe this should match the following kind of string:

```
char [] myCharArray = {'a', 's', 'e'};
String fruits = "Apples Bananas and Grapes";
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0 ?=.*a?=.*s?=.*e
```

Comment: This looks like far far away from the solution to what I think you want to do. Are you trying to check if a string has all the letters you need? For example, array is {a,e,i,o,u} so "This" matches and "Ths" does not match. Yes?

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're trying to build,

```
(?=.*a)(?=.*s)(?=.*e)
```

for the full expression of,

```
^(?=.*s)(?=.*e)(?=.*a).*$
```

which,

```
myRegex.append(String.format("(?=.*%c)", c));
```

may partially work.

---

Being said that, a positive lookahead for each char is not really efficient or the best idea here, because each one is an O(N) time complexity.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3pnPc1/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/3pnPc1/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){


        final String regex = "^(?=.*s)(?=.*e)(?=.*a).*$";
        final String string = "Apples Bananas and Grapes\n"
             + "Some String that doeS not have A lower S or E or A";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
 Full match: Apples Bananas and Grapes
```